# $wpdb not work in another page

Tags: wordpress

i create simple plugin , it work in main page , but when i create a link to user go to the another page for see informaation , it show me Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_results()

my code is :

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_customers");
?>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>‌ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Family</th>
        <th>Numbers</th>
        <th>Tell</th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach($results as $results){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $results->id; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $results->name; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $results->family; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $results->numbers; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $results->tell; ?>
        </td>
        <?php }?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: have you set up the database prefix to something other than 'wp_'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check you have not set up the database prefix to something other than 'wp_'.

And if you have wp_ prefix in the database then you have to included wp-load file on the custom page.

```
require( '/path/to/wp-load.php' );
```

Comment: hello , i am new in wordpress programing , it's give me error to use requre 
how can i requre that ?

Comment: That's not the proper way to write a plugin, please take a look at this https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Answer (score 0):

If it's a plugin then you should encapsulate your code in a function and hook this funtion to the wordpress "init" action, so in your plugin file you should have somthing like this :

```
function your_function_name_here($some_params){
  return "some results";
}

add_action('init', 'your_function_name_here');
```

Comment: in the page i want show the information i must write this ? or any page ?

Comment: You said it was a plugin right ? is it a short code based plugin ? or a widget ? tell me more so i can help you if i can.

Comment: it wide , i have 5 php page , and one for get information and insert to db from user , and one of them for sho information to user

Comment: i am new and if u help me to write standard code i be very happy , unforchently my english not so good , and i need some example code to see and under stand. or read more simple english document @Amin.T